# Error ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pdf2docx'

Tags: python, importerror

I am having an issue to work with the lib pdf2docx.
Here is the code I am trying to work

```
from pdf2docx import Converter

pdf_file = 'test_file.pdf'
docx_file = 'test_file.docx'
# convert pdf to docx
cv = Converter(pdf_file)
cv.convert(docx_file, start=0, end=None)
cv.close()
```

I have installed the lib using pip install pdf2docx and I have tried as well to use sudo.

I tried to use as venv like:
create a folder
inside this folder, open your command line(cmd)

```
pip install virtualenv
virtualenv venv
pip install pdf2docx
```

Any idea about how I can make the script working?

Comment: Did you install the package to the right Python environment?

Comment: What is the exact command you use to execute this script?

Answer (score 1):

Require Python >= 3.6. `pdf2docx` can be installed through:

```
 python3 -m pip install pdf2docx
```

Answer (score 0):

I just solved the issue, it looks like I am unable to run the script using Vstudio. The script works using the command line like python3 pdf_to_docx.py.